# Dynamically created button - onclick event not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a file upload control and a upload button in c# code as below: The controls are getting created and are shown in the UI- aspx

```
TableCell uploadCell = new TableCell();
uploadCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
tRow.Cells.Add(uploadCell);

FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
fu.ID = "fu_" + BU + "_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
fu.AllowMultiple = false;     

Button btnUpload = new Button();
btnUpload.ID = "btnUpload_" + BU + "_" + artifact.LookupValue + artifact.LookupId;
btnUpload.Text = "Upload";
btnUpload.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnUpload_Click);    
PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = btnUpload.ID;
uploadCell.Controls.Add(fu);
uploadCell.Controls.Add(btnUpload);
Up1.Triggers.Add(trigger);

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

when I click on the upload button, the click event is not getting fired. I have attached a debug on the `btnUpload_Click`, but that is not hit.

How to trigger the click event for dynamically added control?

Comment: make it `btnUpload.Click += btnUpload_Click;`

Comment: @ASpirin where do you see `runat` or a check with `runat` that has to do with a click event handler?

Comment: Where in the page's life-cycle are you adding this button?  If they are not getting created / added at the correct stage of the life-cycle, the events can't be processed.